# Inequality index

Tags: qgis

Suppose I have a shapefile with n polygons and a raster overlying the shapefile. I would like to find a metric which enables comparing the level of inequality in each polygon (in terms of the raster values), and to compare this metric across polygons to see which are more or less unequal. My intuition would be that of using Zonal Statistics in QGIS to calculate the standard deviation for each polygon, and then compare these values. But isn't the fact that these polygons have different areal extent (i.e. different number of pixels) affecting the comparability of the SD metric?

Comment: So in an expression like `polygon_area = raster_area * N`, you're looking for N, yes? Could you convert the raster to polygons, then compare the two? It's definitely going to depend on the area of the polygon relative to your raster cell size, but you may be able to determine a minimum area-to-cell ratio at which this metric is useful, then discard polygons which fall short.